# urxvt writing over itself and leaving colored spaces

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, rxvt, fish

URXVT is writing over itself and leaving behind colored spaces... I feel like this is easier shown than described:
[image: urxvt overwriting]

This started occurring overnight without making any changes, so I'm not sure where to even start diagnosing the issue.  It does only occur in urxvt, no other applications, although I don't have any other terminal emulators to test on.  I am using a picom branch that has rounded corners, which I forgot the name of but if it's useful I can probably find out, and this is the neofetch output if it's of any use:
[image: neofetch]

Any ideas of what might be causing this  issue or how to fix it?  I haven't seen anything else regarding this issue, and it's not documented in the arch wiki either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually this happens if the terminal emulator renders characters at a different width than what fish expects. Does your prompt have any emoji or CJK characters? Does either of `set -g fish_emoji_width 1` or `set -g fish_emoji_width 2` help>

Comment: I tried, but no luck... I should also note that I tried this in bash as well (which had been working before) and it has the same issue.

Comment: If you make your prompt extremely simple like just `>` does it still occur?